# Слетел перевод строк в окне регистрации

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, регистрация

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/signup

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переводы добавлены. Уже доступны на сайте.

> [image]